# Need help using java threads to download file parts

Tags: java, http, download, range, random-access

I am trying to download a file from a server in a user specified number of parts (n).  So there is a file of x bytes divided into n parts with each part downloading a piece of the whole file at the same time.  I am using threads to implement this, but I have not worked with http before and do not really understand how downloading a file really works.  I have read up on it and it seems "Range" needs to be used, but I do not know how to download different parts and being able to append them without corrupting the data.

Comment: And have you seen any tool like this in your life, the one which will let you download a file in parts over `http`?

Comment: its a homework assignment and I can't find any information to help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Since it's a homework assignment I will only give you a hint)*

Appending to a single file will not help you at all, since this will mess up the data. You have two alternatives:

- Download from each thread to a separate temporary file and then merge the temporary files in the right order to create the final file. This is probably easier to conceive, but a rather ugly and inefficient approach.
- Do not stick to the usual stream-style semantics - use random access ([1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html), [2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/rafs.html)) to write data from each thread straight to the right location within the output file.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  So with the more efficient approach, each part would simultaneously copy bits of the file sort of like with a torrent?  I have been using the HttpConnection object to connect to the URL, so what object type would I use to to do this  random access?  This is the last bit of information I need.  I have no experience with web programming.  Thanks again

Comment: @user1205853: Have a look at the two links in my answer. BTW, random file access is rather basic - it does not have much to do with web programming...